# Change Y axis tick mark emphasis, data series names, and title subtitle in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using a package in RStudio that creates graphs from data generated from a separate program. I'm trying to modify the graphs in RStudio so they are more visually appealing. I would like to remove the emphasis on the `y-axis` tick marks, remove the subtitle from my title, and change the `x-axis` data series names (i.e. instead of data labels 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 20 minutes, I would like to change them to something else).

Here is a `y-axis` tick example:

[image: y axis tick example]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Check out ggplot's [theme elements](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/theme.html) and [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Axes_(ggplot2)/) for examples.